# Typing into the "body" box causes leftover "overlay"

Tags: bug

I'm not sure how to describe this, but whenever I type into "Body" and do some backspacing, the text will appear messed up. Just like this screenshot:

[image: Image showing messed up text]

The situation quickly degrades into more nonsense when I do things like pasting an image, like this:

[image: Image showing messed up UI]

And finally, if I scroll up and down, there will be "overlay" boxes left on the screen, like this:

[image: Overlay boxes left on screen]

For additional tech information:

- Browser: Firefox 120.0.1 (64-bit)
- Not (yet) using [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) or any other script-blockers
- Not using Stylish or any other appearance modifiers
- OS is Windows 10

---

### Update:

Doing "Inspect" on the overlay shows a bunch of `<div>`s, all differing by one character in their contents, like this:

[image: Inspect on the "overlay"]

#### However

The same behavior does *not* happen when I *edit* the question. It seems to only happen when I type a new question/answer.

---

### Update 2:

I happen to see the same 'bug' on another site ... which makes me suspicious that it might be caused by an extension I use.

Currently doing binary elimination of extensions I'm using.